# How to deploy modules separately in single page application (SPA)?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, single-page-application

I want to build an admin panel with single-spa framework and vue3 or react framework where the below features needs:

1. user management should be separate deployed
2. role management should be separate deployed
3. rule management should be separate deployed
4. resource management should be separate deployed
5. database api DataStax Astra

All module will be Single Page Application and separately deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Datastax does provide a repository of sample projects. I think it would be a helpful resource to your project.

https://github.com/DataStax-Examples